# attr id with two words in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a javascript:

```
var menuname = $(this).attr('id');
alert(menuname);
```

This gets the id of this anchor:

```
<a class=\"menuname\" id=" .$value['menuname']. " href='#' value=" .$value['menuname']. ">".$value['menuname']."</a>
```

My question is:

How to make the id accept two words.

For example: I want the id to be `Hello World` in this case, it only accepts the id to be `Hello` so I cant reference it properly.

I tried to search for ideas on this but all I found is how to just get the first word of the two words phrase it is not what I want any suggestions is appreciated.

Update:

Using attribute id is not an option now making use of attr value still same result i still get the first letter only which i need it to be the two letter value of attr value any idea is appreciated

Comment: An ID must be one word. period

Comment: @myfunkyside well, it can't contain any spaces

Comment: @Phil - making it one word.. (in programming terms obviously... "identifier" is the term used by wikipedia)

Comment: Writing this as a comment as to not detract from the technically correct answer below, but... this seems so much simpler to me `$menuName = htmlspecialchars($value['menuname']); ?> <a class="menuname" id="<?= $menuName ?>" href="#" value="<?= $menuName ?>"><?= $menuName ?></a>` (not taking into account that ID attributes should **not** contain spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that ID attribute values are supposed to be unique. But the important thing is it gets cut since you do not close the attribute properly.

```
echo "<a class=\"menuname\" id='" .$value['menuname']. "' href='#' value='" .$value['menuname']. "'>".$value['menuname']."</a>";
                      //       ^      quotation         ^
```

Sidenote: This will also mess up the closing attribute quotations when you have strings like:

```
Hello world's of fun!
```

And why it is that you're making this value an ID anyway.

```
echo "<a class=\"menuname\" id='menu_" .$value['id']. "' href='#' value='" .htmlspecialchars($value['menuname'], ENT_QUOTES). "'>".$value['menuname']."</a>";
```

Comment: urgh, `echo`-ing out all that static HTML for 3 (repeated) PHP values. Also, `htmlspecialchars()` would take care of the quotes problem

Comment: because i will use this id as a select parameter in database if you have any other better option than this please do give it to me..in the value part if i use it as attr(value) in javascript will it give me `Hello World`?

Comment: @HogRider the just use `attr('value')`. Its the same anyways. here is an info on what an ID attribute value should have: http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/3859027

Comment: @Ghost i did try to use value sir but still the value should be `Hello World` but i still get `Hello` i think it has something to do with the value i use it this way `value=" .htmlspecialchars($value['menuname'], ENT_QUOTES). ">`

Comment: @HogRider `value` isn't really a valid attribute for anchor tags. Maybe try using `data-value`. Then you can retrieve it via jQuery's `$(this).data('value')`

Comment: @Phil yeah thats a better idea and the proper way. use `data-value` data tags instead.

Answer (score 1):

you must have id in a single word
You have two choice to do this 
1. Just Replace the white space with _

```
 <a class=\"menuname\" id=" .str_replace(' ','_',$value['menuname']. " href='#' value=" .$value['menuname']. ">".$value['menuname']."</a>
```

2. you can specify new attribute

   ```
     <a class=\"menuname\" datagroup=" .$value['menuname']. " href='#' value=" .$value['menuname']. ">".$value['menuname']."</a>
   ```

   var menuname = $(this).attr('datagroup');
   alert(menuname);